# Items repeating when scrolling in ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, scroll, adapter

I am using a custom adapter in my listview. When I print out my data in my arraylist, it is stored correctly, though when I scroll items repeat. I know my getView method is kind of jumbled and confusing, though why is it not representing my arraylist data, "oslist," correctly?

Here is my adapter code:

```
public class WXYCAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private FragmentActivity context;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> oslist;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> heartList;

private LayoutInflater mInflater;

private final static int STREAM_LAYOUT = 0;
private final static int TALKSET_LAYOUT = 1;
private final static int BREAKPOINT_LAYOUT = 2;
private final static int PLAYCUT_LAYOUT = 3;
private final static int NULL_LAYOUT = 4;

String URL;
ViewHolder holder;

public WXYCAdapter(FragmentActivity context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> oslist) {
    this.context = context;
    this.oslist = oslist;
    this.mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.oslist.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    int RETURN_LAYOUT = NULL_LAYOUT;

    switch (oslist.get(position).get("layoutType")) {
        case "LiveStream":
            RETURN_LAYOUT = STREAM_LAYOUT;
            break;

        case "Playcut":
            RETURN_LAYOUT = PLAYCUT_LAYOUT;
            break;

        case "Talkset":
            RETURN_LAYOUT = TALKSET_LAYOUT;
            break;

        case "Breakpoint":
            RETURN_LAYOUT = BREAKPOINT_LAYOUT;
            break;
    }

    return RETURN_LAYOUT;

}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 4;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    holder = null;
    int type = getItemViewType(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        switch (type) {
            case STREAM_LAYOUT:
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_cell, null);

                holder.cell_image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cell_image);
                holder.cell_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.boombox);

                holder.song = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.song);
                holder.artist = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.artist);

                holder.song.setEnabled(false);
                holder.song.setMaxHeight(0);

                holder.artist.setEnabled(false);
                holder.artist.setMaxHeight(0);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
                break;

            case TALKSET_LAYOUT:
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_cell, null);

                holder.cell_image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cell_image);
                holder.cell_image.setImageBitmap(null);
                holder.cell_image.setEnabled(false);
                holder.cell_image.setMaxHeight(0);
                holder.cell_image.setMaxWidth(0);

                holder.song = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.song);
                holder.artist = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.artist);
                holder.song.setText("Talkset");
                holder.artist.setText(null);

                holder.artist.setEnabled(false);
                holder.artist.setMaxHeight(0);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
                break;

            case BREAKPOINT_LAYOUT:
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_cell, null);

                holder.cell_image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cell_image);
                holder.cell_image.setImageBitmap(null);
                holder.cell_image.setEnabled(false);
                holder.cell_image.setMaxHeight(0);
                holder.cell_image.setMaxWidth(0);

                holder.song = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.song);

                //holder.song.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "default.ttf"));

                holder.artist = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.artist);
                holder.song.setText("Breakpoint");
                holder.artist.setText(null);
                holder.artist.setEnabled(false);
                holder.artist.setMaxHeight(0);


                long l = Long.parseLong(oslist.get(position).get("hour"));

                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.setTimeInMillis(l);
                calendar.setTimeInMillis(l * 1000);

                int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
                break;

            case PLAYCUT_LAYOUT: //Playcut


                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_cell, null);


                //holder.cell_image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cell_image);

                //holder.cell_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_album_art);

                holder.song = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.song);
                holder.artist = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.artist);

                holder.song.setText(oslist.get(position).get("songTitle"));
                holder.artist.setText(oslist.get(position).get("artistName"));

                convertView.setTag(holder);
                break;
            case NULL_LAYOUT:
                convertView.setTag(holder);
                break;

        }


    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    return convertView;

}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds(){
    return true;
}



public static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView textView, song, artist;


    public ImageView cell_image;
    public Button playButton;
}
```

}

Comment: I'm pretty sure that your sample code could be pared down from its current 198 lines (almost 6K characters). Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I fixed it! I just had to move the switch case below the if-else statement. Not entirely sure why.. but if anyone would like to explain, I would love to learn

Answer (score 2):

Listview should reuse a view. So, same view can be used in other items of the list.

The main problem is that you are changing the view's content only if the view is null

**Wrong way**

```
If(convertView == null) {
    //Inflate view
    // Change view content
}
```

Since the view can be reused, it is not always null.

As you said, issue was fixed after you moved the switch statement to outside of null condition.

This way, view content will be always changed according to current item (which is correct)

**Right way**

```
If(convertView == null) {
    // inflate it
}
// Change view content
```

This caused confusion to me also at the beginning...
View is reused.. But you should change its content accordingly.

Comment: This answer is spot on. Only thing I would add is in the `If(convertView == null) { // inflate it }` <--View was created,... and in the `else {  holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(); }` <-- View was recycled. Move your switch to after the if/else statement and before the return and you're good to go.